# non-visible character in modified column

Tags: oracle, character, regexp-replace, nls-sort

I have a string, which is arranged in a string without spaces and some characters and without punctuation. In final string is 6 characters "ABCDEF" but length is 7. Why? 
It is in ORACLE.

```
select 
 regexp_replace((upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(trim('a.Bc d-E/f'), 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))), '[/:.,- ]|\d', '') as column_1
,length(regexp_replace((upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(trim('a.Bc d-E/f'), 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))), '[/:.,- ]|\d', '')) as length_1
from dual
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap the regexp_replace in a dump() call to see the actual characters output in hex.  I suspect you have a space in there that is not obvious in the output.

Comment: select dump(regexp_replace((upper(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(trim('a.Bc d-E/f'), 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))))), '[/:.,- ]|\d\p{Nd}\p{L}\p{P}\s\w', '')) from dual

Typ=1 Len=7: 65,66,67,68,69,70,0
Why is there 0 ? How can I edit it only for 6 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2() adds the null terminator to the string which LENGTH() counts:

```
SQL> select
    dump(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('a.Bc d-E/f', 'nls_sort=binary_ai')
) as column_1
   from dual;

COLUMN_1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Typ=1 Len=11: 97,46,98,99,32,100,45,101,47,102,0

SQL>
```

Comment: It looks like that. How can I edit utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2() for none the null terminator?

Comment: Remove the last character with a call to substr().  First I'd do a little searching to make sure other calls are doing what you expect.